# Laravel routing: skip parameter if empty

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I am encountering some problems with my routes in Laravel.
For example I have the following url:

```
example.com/ads/all/experience:10-30;/wo/page-5
```

Where the params are respectively the controller, the category, the sliders vars (don't mind the weird format, it is javascript generated), the level of education and the page (number).

For this url to function correctly, I use the following route:

```
Route::get ( 'ads/{category}/{sliders?}/{education?}/{page?}' , 'AdsController@getIndex' )
        -> where ( 'sliders?' , '(hours|experience):([0-9]+)-([0-9]+);' )
        -> where ( 'education?' , '(mbo|hbo|wo)' )
        -> where ( 'page?' , '(page-|page)([0-9])*' );
```

Now the problem is: I would like for people to be able to just enter a part of the url. For example:

```
example.com/ads/all/page-5
```

Would simply display all ads that are listed on page 5. Or:

```
example.com/ads/all/wo/page-3
```

Which would display all ads with education level 'wo' that are listed on page 3.

I hoped that because I used the optional option for the parameters '?' and because of the regex that laravel would automatically recognise when a parameter is not fulfilled and the controller would get something like this:

```
getIndex ( $categories = 'all' , $sliders = null , $education = 'wo' , $page = '3' )
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't. Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this (except for reordering the parameters, which is not an option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So eventually I managed to get it working with this code. Hope it helps someone else too.

```
Route::get ( 'ads/{category}/{a?}/{b?}/{c?}' , function ( $category , $a = false , $b = false , $c = false )
{
    $params = array ( $a , $b , $c );
    $slider = $education = $page = false;

    foreach ( $params as $p )
    {
        if ( $p && preg_match ( '/(mbo|hbo|wo)/' , $p ) )
            { $education = $p; }

        elseif ( $p && preg_match ( '`^[a-zA-Z0-9+/]+={0,2}$`' , $p ) )
            { $slider = $p; }

        elseif ( $p && preg_match ( '/(page-|page)([0-9])*/' , $p ) )
            { $page = $p; }
    }

    return App::make ( 'AdsController' ) -> getIndex ( $category , $slider , $education , $page );

} );
```

Comment: Just so you know, this would be considered bad practice though. Having multiple URLs that refer to the same thing is kinda against the idea of URLs. And SEO-wise (if that's something you consider) you will have multiple content. You should at least ensure you set a `<link rel="canonical">` tag in your head that uses the proper full-form URL if this is a public page.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I will definitely include the canonical link.

Comment: 1 year later I can say this saved my life, thanks for posting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

First reason yours won't work `coz you have a syntax error.

```
-> where ( 'sliders?'
```

You should remove the `?`'s there. Like so:

```
-> where ( 'sliders'
```

Another thing is, you have misconception of things.

Let's say we have:

```
Route::get('{a?}/{b?}/{c?}', 'someController@sample');
// then your sample function have
sample($a = 'apple', $b = 'banana', $c = 'carrot')
```

Now, I'll give URI examples and what are the result you should expect:

```
your_site/a/b/c
// $a = 'a'; $b = 'b'; $c = 'c';

your_site/a/c
// $a = 'a'; $b = 'c'
```

The explanation is, it only matches two parameters on the uri thus filling only the first two param of the function. `->where` or `::pattern` doesn't help change that either.

The use of using a pattern is, for example:

```
Route::pattern('int','[0-9]');
Route::pattern('str','[a-z]');

Route::get('ads','adsController@index');
Route::get('ads/{int?}','intController@index');
Route::get('ads/{str?}','strController@index');

your_site/ads // will use adsController@index
your_site/ads/1 // will use intController@index
you_site/ads/a // will use strController@index
you_site/ads/a1 // will produce an error
```

Of course you can choose to use 1 controller for all three but uses different functions for each. This depends now on how you program your ctrls.

Hope this clear things up.

So I suggest you do something similar to my last example. Make a route rules for each possible param combination you want and, yeah...

Comment: I do not agree with the fact that there is a syntax error: if you leave the '?' out, Laravel will throw an error actually...
Furthermore: your example with apple's and banana's: I get that that is how it works. However, it is not the way I wanted it to work. What you are doing here is explaining why it doesn't work.

Regarding your possible solution. That is somewhat like what I did to solve it.